# Fix menu after woocommerce update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have two main menus - One on either side of my logo. After a woocommerce update, the right hand menu is messed up. I have tried some CSS code but I just can't get it to move back to where it should be.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this please? I can't seem to move the cart back to next to my account and I can't move the search icon back to the far right. The site is www.ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za

Thanks

[image: Menu Before / After]

Comment: search code in the navbar-logo. please share your header.php code

Comment: You should never update to a "just released" WooCommerce major version and you should **always wait** at least 1 month, as there is always a lot of bugs that will be solved in the following upcoming minor versions. You need also to check your theme authors threads, to see if the theme is compatible with this new WooCommerce release 3.7.x (and also your related plugins). If you have made some customizations on WooCommerce templates, also check that they are up to date. Advice: You should better revert back to last 3.6.5 previous version.

Comment: I've added my header.php code to the question

Comment: @LoicTheAztec So do you not 'HAVE' to update the woocommerce plugin because they release one? I was worried if I don't update it something will go wrong because it's too old

Comment: On new major release *(like here: 3.7)*, always wait at least 1 month (even more if possible). The version 3.6.5 works just nice and you don't need to update ASAP. Major updates gives new functionalities and is better to wait some time until bugs are solved. Also themes and plugins need to be compatible (and up to date). Last thing: if you have done customizations, you may need to update your code (or WooCommerce templates) depending on the changes of that new release…